# how to get the most happy department from given feedback of the Employees using SQL query

Tags: sql

Given : Employee Table

Find the most happy department

```
|------------------------|
| EMP_ID | Dept | Rating |
|------------------------|
|001     | HR   |  3     |
|------------------------|
|002     | HR   |  5     |
|------------------------|
|003     | MR   |   3    |
|------------------------|
|004     | IT   |   3    |
|------------------------|
|005     | IT   |   1    |
|------------------------|
|006     | HR   |   1    |
|------------------------|
```

.....
.......

Comment: I see nothing in the data that relates to being "happy".  If the rating is somehow involved, then you would seem to want a simple `group by` query.

Comment: How do you determine happy ?, it it average rating?

Comment: I am sorry, I am following a code of conduct.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's wonderful to have you here. Have you tried to anything already? You'll find that people are much more willing to answer - and you get much better answers as a result - if you show what you've already done, and ask specific questions about where you're struggling. As it stands, this looks a little bit like a homework question, where you're just hoping people will do the work for you. I'm sure that's not the case, but if you show that you've already made some effort, people are more likely to want to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work fine for you, remove top 1 if needed:

```
declare @t table (EMP_ID int, Dept char(2), Rating int)
insert into @t values
(001,     'HR',      3),
(002,     'HR',      5),
(003,     'MR',      3),
(004,     'IT',      3),
(005,     'IT',      1),
(006,     'HR',      1),
(007,     'MR',      3),
(008,     'IT',      5),
(009,     'IT',      2),
(010,     'HR',      2)


select top 1 Dept, avg(rating) 
from @t 
group by Dept
order by avg(rating) desc
```

EDIT:
Below is more accurate version:

```
select top 1 Dept,
    avg(cast(rating as float)) 
from @t 
group by Dept
order by avg(cast(rating as float)) desc
```

> Please note:

Above queries will return only one department even if there is more than 1 department with the same highest average rating.

> Below query will return all Departments with highest average rank

```
select Dept,
    avg(cast(rating as float)) 
from @t 
group by Dept
having avg(cast(rating as float)) = (select top 1 avg(cast(rating as float)) 
                                    from @t 
                                    group by Dept
                                    order by avg(cast(rating as float)) desc)
```